# Raspberry pi 4 with two webcams

Tags: raspbian, webcam, raspberry-pi-os

I am trying to run two webcams on raspberry pi 4 with raspbian OS. It works rarely with very low FPS. Most of the time i am getting this error:

```
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-wheel-qd18ncao/opencv-python/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (1004) tryIoctl VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): select() timeout. No more frames
```

I removed uvcvideo module from OS and then i installed it with new parameters:

```
sudo rmmod uvcvideo
sudo modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=5000 quirks=0x80
```

Cameras works fast but there is a problem on right camera:
[image]

If i run cameras one bye one, there is no problem.

I need to run two cameras together, how can i fix it?